# How to detect user inactivity in an Excel workbook

Tags: vba, excel, timer, user-inactivity

I want to take an action in an Excel workbook macro after a period of inactivity (hide/protect some worksheets).  What is the best/simplest way to achieve this?

Í'm assuming I'll use `Application.OnTime` to periodically check if the user has been active.  But what events should I handle to see if the user was "active" (i.e. has does something - anything - with the workbook)?

Clarification: I want to detect *all* activity, not just changes.  I.e. including mouse clicks, selecting, copying, navigating with the keyboard, changing worksheets, ...

I'm assuming that when a UI event happens that represents user activity, I will set a variable thus:

```
LastActivityTime = Now
```

and the macro run by `Application.OnTime` will check this variable to see if the user has been active recently.  Which events (other than `SheetChange`) would I need to handle to set this variable?  I had kind of hoped there would be `KeyUp` and `MouseUp` events, these two would probably have been enough.

Update: I have implemented this by handling `Workbook_SheetActivate`, `Workbook_SheetSelectionChange` and `Workbook_WindowActivate`.  Realistically this is probably enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have implemented this by handling Workbook_SheetActivate, Workbook_SheetSelectionChange and Workbook_WindowActivate. Realistically this is probably enough.

Answer (score 2):

I can only see two solutions -- either handle evary single event the Application object has or use [GetLastInputInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646302.aspx) function.

Comment: GetLastInputInfo sounds promising but seems to be related to the user session rather than an application.  I am only interested in user activity related to my Excel workbook - or the Excel process would do.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to compare the content of the workbook with that of the last time you check. I believe combining this with Application.OnTime will solve your concern.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to detect activity that doesn't change the workbook too.  I've added some clarification to my question.